# zipped the file that belongs to same months

Tags: python, zip

I have a folder named "DataFiles", there are files like:
2016-04-26.csv, 2016-04-27.csv,2016-05-12.csv...
I want to zip the csv files that belongs to same months...
for that i trying the below code:

```
import datetime
import os
import zipfile

yearP= None
monthP = None

for csvfiles in os.listdir("DataFiles"):
    csvname, formata = csvfiles.split(".")
    year, month, date = csvname.split("-")
    if (yearP==year and monthP == month):
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile('%s.zip' %monthyear , 'a') 
        zip.write('%s.csv' %csvname ) 
        yearP= year
        monthP = month
    else:
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile('%s.zip' %monthyear , 'a') 
        zip.write('%s.csv' %csvname )   
        yearP= year
        monthP = month
```

but because of not in the sorted order it returns unusual results. I want to zip the according to the month and named the zipped file as  the respective monthyear.

Comment: How many `.csv`s are there? You could sort them, partition by month, then zip each partition.

Comment: more than 20 @ erip

Comment: sort them by date and then write it in a zipfile accordingly

Comment: What do you mean about not in the sorted order? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @martineau Consider your months in order `04, 05, 04`.

Comment: without sorting it compares and give wrong results, what is the sorting function for filenames in python @v.coder

Comment: You need to sort the results that `os.listdir()` produces. You can sort it by using the built-in `sorted()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Since your files are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can lexicographically sort them.

Replace

```
for csvfiles in os.listdir("DataFiles"):
```

with

```
for csvfiles in sorted(os.listdir("DataFiles")):
```

---

This may become less tractable with a huge number of .csv files and you may need to rethink your algorithm, but for a small number, it's fine.